# Handlehttp processor in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to post a json request to the handlehttp processor in Nifi. Could this be achieved as currently i am getting a 0 byte file passed to the flowfile. Is there any way we can pass the json request through the flowfile?
Thanks

[image]

This the sample URL i am posting using python requests library.
requests.post(localhost:6202/sample,json={"id":1,"name":"test"}

[image]

Comment: The flow file coming out of HandleHttpRequest should have the JSON in the content, have you tried stopping ReplaceText and listing the queue before it to look at the flow file? I'm thinking maybe ReplaceText is overwriting your content.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Bryan. When i am passing the parameters as a query string in URL i am able to receive. Is there any config which needs to be added to the handleHTTP Request or in replace text  in order to get the passed json parameters?

Comment: I am currently using ${http.query.string} in replace text processor. I need the json parameters passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flow is showing no flow files being transferred, rather than 0-byte flow files being transferred. Do you mean that you are getting a 404 response in your flow? If so, that is because you do not have a HandleHttpResponse in the flow to return a status code. I was able to get

```
requests.post("http://localhost:6202/sample",json={"id":1,"name":"test"})
```

to work with a HandleHttpRequest -> LogAttribute -> HandleHttpResponse flow.

Comment: Tried by adding HandleHttpResponse. Getting  404 response. 
I am able to receive a 200 status code as response when i try to hit with the below url directly from the browser.
localhost:6688/sample?id=1&name=test

Comment: Can you share your HandleHttpRequest config?

Comment: Edited the post by sharing the HandleHttpRequest config

Comment: I am able to get the query parameters passed through the url through ${http.query.url} from replace text processor. 
But i want to get the json request made to it.
Like the way i am passing the json mentioned in the above sample url.

Comment: I can get the JSON body using the requests command (and flow) I posted above, did you see Bryan’s comment about ReplaceText?

Comment: Have tested for both /sample and /test in the url